# Retrieve the mac address of a remote pc Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I just want to know how to get the mac address of a remote computer.

```
void LocateAddress()
{
    QString host = "192.168.1.1";

    .....function for getting the mac address....

}
```

Is there a way to create a function that retrieves the Mac Address of a remote pc???
Using ng Windows OS

Comment: Probably too late for you, but surely very useful for someone still looking on how to do it properly using Qt (for Windows): [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52814472/4731718) Cheers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `arp -a 192.168.1.1` on the command line you can get that information if you just need it once.

If you want to do it programmatically, there is a SendARP function in the windows API, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Note that this only works on your local network, there must be no routers between you and the target computer.